# gasのTextInputの挙動について(gmailアドオンの開発)

Tags: google-apps-script

Gmailのアドオンの開発を行っています。

[CardのTextInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input)のsetValueでデフォルト値を設定し、ユーザーが値を削除した場合、デフォルト値が入ってしまいます。
ユーザーが値を削除した場合は未入力のままであるべきだと思うのですが、仕様でしょうか。

下記がデフォルト値の設定処理です。

```
  var textValue = CardService.newTextInput()
  .setMultiline(true)
  .setFieldName('textValue')
  .setTitle('テキスト入力フィールド')
  .setValue('defaultvalue');
```

下記がTextInputの値を取得する処理です。

```
var textValue = e && e.formInput['textValue'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

本事象は現時点では起きていないので、解消されたようです。
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80269537